# URL navigation in three20

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I am fairly new to three20 so bear with me. I have the following code which loads objects to the data source:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    RKObjectTTTableViewDataSource* dataSource = [RKObjectTTTableViewDataSource dataSource];
    [dataSource mapObjectClass:[Group class] toTableCellClass:[CCell class]];
    RKObjectLoader* objectLoader = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectLoaderWithResourcePath:@"/groups.json" delegate:nil];
    dataSource.model = [RKObjectLoaderTTModel modelWithObjectLoader:objectLoader];
    self.dataSource = dataSource;
}
```

I have set up a URL map in the appdelegate as follows:

```
TTNavigator *navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
    navigator.window = self.window;

    TTURLMap *map = navigator.URLMap;
    [map from:@"tt://topics/(initWithTopicsIndex:)" 
    toSharedViewController:[TopicsViewController class]];
```

I would like to push another controller when I tap on the cell, how do I do this? Can I do this via the setObject in the TTTableViewCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your item class needs to return the URL you want to navigate to in the URLValue method. URLValue is implemented in a category on NSObject and uses the URLMap to create URL for objects.

If your item is subclass of TTTableLinkedItem, it has a URL property, which is used instead.

Have a look at `[TTTableViewController didSelectObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath]`

and `[TTTableViewDelegate tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath]`

Comment: I did looked at didSelectRowAtIndexPath and it does print something when I clicked on the rows

Comment: What does it print? Is execution anytime reaching `TTOpenURLFromView(URL, self.view);` in either of these methods? What does the URL you are trying to open look like?

Comment: Maybe I am not giving enough information here, I have a custom cell that subclasses the  TTTableLinkedItemCell and everything is set via the setObject:(id)object method. Yes the item is a subclass of TTTableLinkedItem, but the URL is not set yet before the setObject method.

I did a NSLog on the - (void)didSelectObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath , that prints the URL of object, but it is null. Why is this? I have set this URL on the setObject.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you are trying to do. I don't see any reason why this should not work, but I do not see a reason why you would want to do it that way, either. Why can't you set the URL before? What dataSource class are you using? Does your dataSources `tableView:objectForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation use any kind of copying?

Comment: let me ask the question this way, I actually want a TTTableTextItem which has an image and a description text under the main text area. How do I do this? Should I subclass it an just add a TTImage and a text area under neath it? How do I set the position of the TTImage, etc